# Split an array from a function into variables, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

Problem: from a function I get two values, and only two. I fill the values into an array and I return the array.
Then I try to assign the two values to two different variables to use later on.

In a `print_r` I can see the values - they are correct, so my sql is ok.
But I cannot split the values into two variables. Help!

The relevant code is here:
The function:

```
$Data = getdatastigning($stignr1);
```

Here I fill the array from a sql statement:

```
$dataArray = array();

$res = $stmt->fetch();

$dataArray[] = $res;

return $dataArray;
```

Here the array is used included the function:

```
$Data = getdatastigning($stignr1);   //function to get hight and length

foreach ($Data as $name){
   print_r($name) . "<br/>";
}
```

As I said the `print_r` shows the values perfect. But I cannot find out to split the array.

I have tried something like:

```
$hight = $Data[0];
$length = $Dat[1);
```

But that is not the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [list()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) construct:

```
list($hight, $length) = getdatastigning($stignr1);
```

The array elements will be assigned to the variables `$hight` and `$length`.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, fetch() already returns an object (depending) or **fetchAll()** returns an array, so you're storing an array ($res) inside another array ($dataArray).

All you need to do is return $res from your function, then inside your foreach(), use list()

```
list($hight, $length) = $Data;
```

or, to make it a bit easier without the secondary variable:

```
list($hight,$length) = getdatastigning($stignr1);
```